# How can I catch the mongodb error to pass the test in jest?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, jestjs

I create a user schema using mongoose.

/src/server/models/User.ts:

```
import { model, Schema } from "mongoose";

export const UserSchema = new Schema({
  address: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  name: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
});

const User = model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

I try to test the insertion of a user object that missed the name in order to get an error returned back from mongodb:

/src/**tests**/db.spec.ts:

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose, { Model } from "mongoose";
import { UserSchema } from "../server/models/User";

let mongoServer: MongoMemoryServer;
const opts = {
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

describe("Users", () => {
  let User: Model<any>;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    mongoServer = new MongoMemoryServer();
    const mongoUri = await mongoServer.getConnectionString();
    const db = await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, opts);
    User = db.model("User", UserSchema);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.disconnect();
    await mongoServer.stop();
  });

  describe("User Creation", () => {
    it("Should returns an error if a name is missing", async () => {
      const newUser = new User({
        address: "address",
        email: "user@gmail.com",
      });
      const createdUser = await User.create(newUser);
      expect(createdUser).toThrow("User validation failed");
    });
  });
});
```

The test failed and I got this error:

```
● Users › User Creation › Should returns an error if a name is missing

    ValidationError: User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.

      at new ValidationError (node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:31:11)
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.invalidate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2413:32)
      at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2262:17)
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1058:9
```

How can I  fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [jest/rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#rejects), I used rejects to pass my test:

```
it("Should returns an error if a name is missing", async () => {
      const newUser = new User({
        address: "address",
        email: "user@gmail.com",
      });
       await expect(User.create(newUser)).rejects.toThrow("Path `name` is required")
    });
```